# Cobertura showing wrong line coverage

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I see a strange cobertura report. It says that line number 89 (see screenshot)

> siteMapItems = getItemFromPage(navParentPage, 0);

is executed once, but the method called on this line (getItemFromPage) shows no line coverage. I have also added logs in the method and i also see logs being printed during execution of unit test case.

What could be the reason of this strange report? Its not making sense to me.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that an exception is getting thrown when line 90 is executed by the test. Maybe there is a bogus "catch (Exception e) {}" somewhere?

Comment: @Rogério: No, there is no catch (Exception e ..) code anywhere. Also, if you see line 122 (LOG.info...). The logs get printed correctly.

Comment: If no exception is ocurring, I see no reason for the red lines... Maybe it's some bug in the Cobertura tool? If possible, you could try a different tool, such as JaCoCo.

Comment: Can you upload a repro case somewhere?

Comment: Probably you only need to clean the project(delete all generated files, classes, etc) and then compile it again. Finally run the test again.

Comment: @Ankit were you able to find the root cause for this issue? I'm also facing the same.

Comment: @Coder: No, never found solution, seems like a issue with cobertura.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally this kind of desynchronization issues arise from mismatch of java files and class files. Check if cobertura is scanning right class file.